# How do I enable "blame" when using git instaweb?

Tags: git, gitweb

From the working directory of a git repository, I start git instaweb using `git instaweb --httpd=webrick`. However, in the tree view of the resulting website, there is no link to each file's "blame". I tried to enable "blame" by adding the following to `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[gitweb]
    blame = true
```

Even after I restart git instaweb (`git instaweb stop`, `git instaweb --httpd=webrick`), the "blame" links are still missing. How do I enable "blame" when using git instaweb?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitweb#Documentation/gitweb.txt-arguments

Comment: @phd Thank you for the link, but I've already read `man 1 gitweb` a few times. Could you elaborate? I have already tried adding `$feature{'blame'}{'default'} = [1];` into the repository's `.git/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl` file, but that file gets overwritten every time git instaweb is restarted.

Comment: Well, I don't use `instaweb`, I use https://packages.debian.org/buster/gitweb from Debian under Apache so my `gitweb_config.perl` is actually `/etc/apache2/sites-available/$domain.perl` and it doesn't get overridden.

Comment: Similar question on the serverfault site: [gitweb refusing to blame](https://serverfault.com/questions/551762/gitweb-refusing-to-blame).

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `/etc/gitweb-common.conf` like this:

```bash
sudo cat >> /etc/gitweb-common.conf <<EOF
\$feature{'highlight'}{'default'} = [1];
\$feature{'blame'}{'default'} = [1];
EOF
```

It should work now. But do notice that you might run into other problems, e.g. AppArmor. If that is the case, please take a look into this post: [Problem with `git instaweb` on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed: /etc/gitweb-common.conf is not being read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77789216/problem-with-git-instaweb-on-opensuse-tumbleweed-etc-gitweb-common-conf-is-n).

A full explanation of the issue with configuration files can be found here: [gitweb refusing to blame](https://serverfault.com/questions/551762/gitweb-refusing-to-blame).