# Problem with `git instaweb` on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed: /etc/gitweb-common.conf is not being read

Tags: git, gitweb, apparmor

`git instaweb` is a very convenient command to browse a repository. But several interesting features are disabled by default.

The main configuration file (`.git/gitweb/gitweb_config.perl`) is rewritten every time `git instaweb` is ran, so it is not possible to store configuration there.

I tried to enable some of the wanted features by creating a global configuration file.

Initially I tried creating `/etc/gitweb.conf`, with the following two lines:

```
$feature{'highlight'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'blame'}{'default'} = [1];
```

But it did not work. Then I tried to create the file `/etc/gitweb-common.conf`. It also did not work.

These lines have no effect on the resulting web interface, I keep receiving `403 - Blame view not allowed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspecting the source code of `/usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi`, I noticed that if the global configuration is read from the file in the variable $GITWEB_CONFIG, which is our particular repository freshly generated configuration file, then the script will never try to read the file in $GITWEB_CONFIG_SYSTEM (`/etc/gitweb.conf`), returning before that happend. So, in this case, using this file does not apply.

But there was no explanation for not reading $GITWEB_CONFIG_COMMON (`/etc/gitweb-common.conf`), which is read before $GITWEB_CONFIG.

After some research, I tried to debug the CGI script in `/usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.cgi` using rudimentary `print` statements. Eventually I converged to the following subroutine:

```perl
# read and parse gitweb config file given by its parameter.
# returns true on success, false on recoverable error, allowing
# to chain this subroutine, using first file that exists.
# dies on errors during parsing config file, as it is unrecoverable.
sub read_config_file {
    my $filename = shift;
    return unless defined $filename;
    # die if there are errors parsing config file
    if (-e $filename) {
        do $filename;
        die $@ if $@;
        return 1;
    }
    return;
}
```

Perl uses two different variables to manage errors from a `do`. One is `$@`, which is set in this case when `do` is unable to compile the file. The other is `$!`, which is set in case `do` cannot read the file. By printing the value of `$!` I found out that it was set to `Permission denied`. Since the script does not currently test for `$!`, the error goes unnoticed. ([Perl do block documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do))

To fix the problem, the following line must be added to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.share.git-web.gitweb.cgi`:

```bash
/etc/gitweb-common.conf r,
```

EDIT: A patch has been sent to the git team and now gitweb.cgi does
test for `$!`.